# System.Diagnostics.Process not being recognized on linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, manjaro

I am on Linux (Manjaro) and it seems like VS Code doesn't know what Process is (see image)
[VS Code tells me that those tokens are not valid in the declaration of a member of the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir89y.png)
Here is the code with the problem

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = MY_EXECUTABLE;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    proc.Start();
    string fingerprint = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Do you have the C# Language support installed in vs-code? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp

Comment: You're trying to write assignment statements *as if they're declarations*. Put that code into a method or constructor declaration instead. Classes don't contain statements directly - they contain declarations (which can include initializers). Note that the claim in the title is incorrect - the screenshot shows that the declaration of the `proc` variable is fine (no warnings) which it wouldn't be if System.Diagnostics.Process wasn't recognized as being a known type name.

Comment: You have to declare a method (`Main` one?) and move the code inside it

Comment: (Also note that this has nothing to do with VS Code or Linux specifically either - the code would be just as invalid compiling on Windows either from the command line or VS...)

Comment: Thank you all,

-C# is indeed installed

-the coloring of "Process" seemed a bit different, causing me to think that it was not recognized

-Putting a method did work, sorry, still a beginner